# Problem with the answers package.

Tags: macros, lists, environments, exercises, answers

I am using the answers package to build a series of exercises. The problem i have encountered is when going from

```
\item $ 5x^2-x \geq 0 $
\begin{sol}
$x \geq 1, x \leq 0$
\end{sol}
```

to

```
\uppg{$x<-2, x>2$}{$-9 < x < 9$}
```

Where uppg looks like

```
\newcommand{\uppg}[2]
{
\item  #1
\begin{sol}
\#2 
\end{sol}
}
```

I keep getting errors because it reads the `\begin{sol}` in `uppg` but ignores the `\end{sol}` and just keeps reading in the file until it realizes it's misstakes and throws an error. How can i resolve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 2):

The `answers` package uses a verbatim-like approach to collect up material. As a result, you *cannot* hide the `\end{sol}` part inside a macro: it has to be in the source as written.

Answer (score 0):

If Joseph is right and it is verbatim-like approach then that is the problem

How `\begin{verbatim}` works. briefly and roughly.

1. `\begin{verbatim}` is expanded to `\verbatim`.
2. Then `\verbatim` sets category code of each special characters to 12. 
   Now all chars is like digits or puncts.
3. Then `\verbatim` sets font, parindent and calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` catches the end of verbatim using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```
5. Then \end{verbatim} finishes work.

How `newcommand{\uppg}[1]{\begin{verbatim}#1\end{verbatim}}` works.

1. `\uppg{$x$}` expands to `\begin{verbatim}$x$\end{verbatim}}`.
2. Then `\begin{verbatim}` expands to `\varbatim`. 
    `\varbatim` changes all categories and font.
3. Then `\verbatim` calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` tries to catch your argument using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```

   but it is impossible because of `\@xverbatim` tries to catch
     `\end` where all letters (`\`,`e`,`n`,`d`) have the category 12 and 11.
     But in fact there are only `\ec` exsits.
5. `\@xverbatim` is trying and trying to find `\end` where backslash (`\`) has category 12 but.... `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim`

Comment: Is there any was around this, to avoid having to repetedly add four lines of code for each assignment, instead of the above *\newcommand* approach?